# Json or separate column?

Tags: mysql, json, table

I'm developing a table structure to store the physical activity data  and users can save their progress. The activities belong to multiple programs. like beginner program suppose be like having 1000 step counts and 100 pushups. The intermediate program would be like like exercise for 30 days and get Saturday off like so. I am confused about whether to store these program info in separate column or as json.

Comment: It depends on what will you do with the data later. If it is for historical use  and you will not perform a lot of queries I would suggest JSON, otherwise use data normalization

Comment: In general, I would _not_ recommend JSON if you're not sure how you will query it. Querying JSON data is usually harder than querying normalized data, so if you lack experience with JSON, you should stick to normal columns.

Comment: From a database perspective, a separate column will never lack anything that a JSON column offers, as long as you're able to normalize the data. But without knowing your use cases or types of queries you'll be running, no specific advisement can be made.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the data's future use and querying requirements is vital when deciding between JSON and data normalization for database storage.

In addition to what others have commented, the consensus is to lean towards data normalization when querying patterns are uncertain or involve frequent and complex queries. JSON may be a suitable choice for historical data with minimal querying needs. The key is to align the data storage strategy with anticipated use cases and querying patterns.